# Use templates created using ckeditor in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating the templates using CKEditor. I need to replace the keys with its value, the keys are stored with its table name and columns to fetch in a table
e.g
tbl_template_bindings

```
   id    key               table       column
    1    StudentFirstName  tbl_User    fname
    2    StudentLastName   tbl_User    lname
    3    TotalAmount       tbl_payment due
```

and the user is bound to use those keys only, a kind of template. so consider we have created below template using CKEditor

```
Date: {{CurrentDate}}
Dear {{StudentFirstName}} {{StudentLastName}}, Your total amount is {{TotalAmount}}
```

please suggest any ideas will be helpful

Comment: the keys are stoered in table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Well, I just made this code for you, because I love CodeIgniter. Unfortunately  I didn't test this code, but I am pretty sure @dEL, you will enjoy :)*

***CodeIgniter Helper File: Templatebuilder_helper.php***

```
if ( ! function_exists('build_ck_template')) {
    /**
     * @param $template_txt
     */
    function build_ck_template($template_txt)
    {
        // get all {{DATA}} as DATA in assoc array
        preg_match_all('/{{(.*?)}}/', $template_txt, $matches);
        // trim data & make array
        $config = array_map('trim', $matches[1]);
        // get CI instance
        $CI = &get_instance();
        // assuming you have user id in session - just for demo
        $uid = $CI->session->userdata('uid');
        // temp array var
        $result = [];
        // get data from table key, table & column
        $query = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_template_bindings");

        // collect all data
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            array_push($result, $row);
        }

        // check one by one array key
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            // skip date because its not in table
            if ($value != 'CurrentDate') {
                // first check if key exist in db data, get index
                $found_at_index = array_search($value, array_column($result, 'key'));

                // yes we got the key
                if (false !== $found_at_index) {
                    // get data for requested key
                    $CI->db->select($result[$found_at_index]['column']);
                    // where clause
                    $CI->db->where('uid', $uid);
                    // query
                    $query = $CI->db->get($result[$found_at_index]['table']);
                    // if uid is unique, we want to return just one row
                    $query_result = array_shift($query->result_array());
                    // get key column data
                    $replace_value = $query_result[$result[$found_at_index]['column']];
                    // replace with original value
                    $template_txt = str_replace('{{'.$value.'}}', $replace_value, $template_txt);
                }
            }
        }

        // return Woah!!!
        $template_txt = str_replace('{{CurrentDate}}', date('Y-m-d'), $template_txt);
        return $template_txt;
    }
}

/* End of file Templatebuild_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/Templatebuilder_helper.php */
```

***Example Uses:***

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Class Controller
 */
class ControllerName extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // load own template helper
        $this->load->helper('Templatebuilder');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        // content template
        $content = "Date: {{CurrentDate}}, Dear {{StudentFirstName}} {{StudentLastName}}, Your total amount is {{TotalAmount}}";
        // build with real values
        $this->load->view('template', array('temp_data' => build_ck_template($content)));
    }
}
/* End of file data.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/ControllerName.php */
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure, but if i understand you correctly you simply need to parse some values and replace it with others

just create a model

```
class Template_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function build($strTemplate, $obj)
    {
        $arrData = (is_object($obj))    ?   get_object_vars($obj)   :   $obj;
        foreach($arrData AS $key => $val)
        {
            $strTemplate = str_replace("{{".$key."}}",$val,$strTemplate);
        }
        return $strTemplate;
    }
}
```

and your controller

```
$this->load->model("template_model");

$str = "Date: {{CurrentDate}}, Dear {{StudentFirstName}} {{StudentLastName}}, Your total amount is {{TotalAmount}}";
echo $this->template_model->build($str, ["CurrentDate" => "2017-05-02", "StudentFirstName" => "Jon", "StudentLastName" => "Doe", "TotalAmount" => 100.22]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CI parsing library to parsing your DB to HTML page.
[CI parsing example](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html)